# save the text value of the file

Tags: python, save

I have a problem. I want to make a login and password in an impromptu program. How do I store the text value of a variable. I ask questions do not ask me I am a Russian-speaking. Piece of code:

```
import os
print("login:")
logg=input(">")
print("password:")
pasw=input(">")
if logg==rlogg or pasw==rpasw:
  <<body programm>>
else:
  <<body programm>>
```

I need to assign the rlogg and rpasw variables to their values ​​in the file. And after that, if the values ​​that were entered in logg and pasw are equal to rlogg and rpasw, then the program continues, if not, then the program is restarted.

Comment: You might be asking something else but it's unclear from your question. It seems that you only want to allow the program to continue if it matches a certain username and password. 

https://gist.github.com/mujeebishaque/92c00353e7745d18202d11b404d29094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question was not very clear, but this example can help you

```
account.txt >> username:passowrd
```

> Save the username and password in the account.txt file

```
#To store information in a file
def save(username,password):
    with open("./account.txt","w") as file:
        file.write(f"{username}:{password}")

def login(username,password):
    with open("./account.txt","r") as file:
        user,passwd = file.read().split(":")
        if username==user and password==passwd:
            return True
        return False

print("login:")
logg=input(">")
print("password:")
pasw=input(">")
if login(logg,pasw):
  print("Login successfully")
else:
  print("Failed login")
```